# How to target this class

Tags: html, css

I have a class I'm trying to target but not sure how.
Here's the code.

```
<article id="post-27346" class="post-27346 forum type-forum status-publish hentry">
    <h1 class="entry-title main_title">Share Experience</h1>
</article>
```

I'm trying to target the word "Share Experience"

Here's my attempt:

```
.forum .main_title {
    margin-bottom: -20px !important;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    padding: 40px 10px 16px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
 }
```

My theory was that .main_title is inside of .forum

Any ideas on how to target this?

Also, is there a way to say target something based on if it has two classes.  So in this case it would be .entry-title AND .main_title?  So I would be saying target only if it has these two classes together.

Comment: Your CSS selector is correct; what problems are you having with it, exactly?

Comment: It looks correct. Please provide a jsfiddle which simulates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope something is overwriting your css. Make specific when styling

Here is a working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h9soprnb/2/)**

```css
.forum h1.main_title {
 margin-bottom: -20px !important;
 background-color: #3f3f3f;
 padding: 40px 10px 16px 10px;
 margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<article id="post-27346" class="post-27346 forum type-forum status-publish hentry">
<h1 class="entry-title main_title">Share Experience</h1>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the label is inside the h1 tag your article classes method is fine. If you want to access a child declaring two classes of the father in this case would look like this :

```
.forum.type-forum .main_title {
 margin-bottom: -20px !important;
 background-color: #3f3f3f;
 padding: 40px 10px 16px 10px;
 margin: 0px 10px -10px 10px;
}
```